How to choose target architecture when using CMakePresets.json to cross-compile for Android in Visual Studio
I am writing a shared library in C++ as a CMake project in Visual Studio 2022. I am able to compile the library as *.dll for Windows, and also an *.so using WSL. I am attempting to compile for Android, but I can't figure out how to choose the architecture.
I'm using the toolchain file provided in the Android NDK:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake

The NDK supports CMake via a toolchain file. Toolchain files are CMake files that customize the behavior of the toolchain for cross-compiling. The toolchain file used for the NDK is located in the NDK at /build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake.


Note: If the Android SDK is installed, then the NDK is installed in the SDK directory in ndk/version/ or ndk-bundle/.


Build parameters such as ABI, minSdkVersion, etc. are given on the command line when invoking cmake. For a list of supported arguments, see the Toolchain arguments section.

Emphasis mine
How do I pass these command line arguments when using a CMakePresets.json file? Do I pass these in CMakeLists.txt? (I've tried this below to no avail).
This is the relevant part of my CMakePresets.json:
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "android-arm64-debug",
            "displayName": "Android Arm64 Debug",
            "description": "Target Android with an Arm64 ABI.",
            "generator": "Ninja",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
            "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
            "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" },
            "toolchainFile": "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.3f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake",
            "condition": {
                "type": "equals",
                "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
                "rhs": "Windows"
            },
            "vendor": { "microsoft.com/VisualStudioRemoteSettings/CMake/2.0": { "remoteSourceRootDir": "$env{HOME}/.vs/$ms{projectDirName}" } }
        },

        # other config removed for clarity ...
    ]
}

My root CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:
set(MY_LIB my_lib)

## This is where I try to override the target architecture ##
if(ANDROID)
    set(ANDROID_ABI arm64-v8a)
endif()
#############################

add_library(${MY_LIB} SHARED api.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${MY_LIB} core)
install(TARGETS ${MY_LIB}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)

The library appears to build successfully, but when I try to import it I get an error telling me that the library is 32-bit instead of 64-bit:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~lBHFmhfxi05kYFW9_9ewXA==/com.example.testlib-SckqPQJeKDtsvK2xuz9oBA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libmy_lib.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
So, it looks like it's using a default from the toolchain file.
Here is the CMake output:
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:/Users/danie/Documents/Workspace/gamechain-lib/out/install/android-arm64-debug" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.3f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake"   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\kyo\Documents\Workspace\my-lib" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:/Users/kyo/Documents/Workspace/my-lib/out/build/android-arm64-debug
1> [CMake] -- ANDROID_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version
1> [CMake] 16.
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done (0.0s)
1> [CMake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/kyo/Documents/Workspace/my-lib/out/build/android-arm64-debug
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted toolchain configurations.
1> Extracted includes paths.


cmake command-line parameters, specified via -D option, in presets are defined in cacheVariables field. E.g. your preset already has CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE parameter.

That's great, thanks. I'm not sure why that was so hard for me to find out.

Thanks to this comment from @Tsyvarev:

cmake command-line parameters, specified via -D option, in presets are defined in cacheVariables field. E.g. your preset already has CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE parameter.

So, I can edit CMakePresets.json, as follows, to set the ANDROID_ABI/ANDROID_PLATFORM etc.:
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "android-arm64-debug",
            "displayName": "Android Arm64 Debug",
            "description": "Target Android with an Arm64 ABI.",
            "generator": "Ninja",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
            "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
                "ANDROID_ABI": "arm64-v8a",
                "ANDROID_PLATFORM": "android-23"
            },
            "toolchainFile": "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.3f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake",
            "condition": {
                "type": "equals",
                "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
                "rhs": "Windows"
            },
            "vendor": { "microsoft.com/VisualStudioRemoteSettings/CMake/2.0": { "remoteSourceRootDir": "$env{HOME}/.vs/$ms{projectDirName}" } }
        },

        # other config removed for clarity ...
    ]
}

